# Hiding the Launcher sidebar of Ubuntu Unity with CompizConfig

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

I am using CompizConfig to hide the Launcher at the side of Ubuntu Unity's home screen. So I followed a tutorial, I went to Ubuntu Unity plugin, and I set the Hide Launcher to autohide, but it still appearing and I can't get rid of it. Anybody has an idea of how to fix this ?

Comment: I think you can do this in system settings then choose appearance and set the launcher to auto hide.

Comment: It won't hide forever if that's what your after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This apparently got broken in Unity when they removed the launcher dodge feature.  The correct way to set the launcher to auto-hide is to open system settings, select "appearance", then open the "behaviour" tab, then turn the autohide feature on.  You don't need CompizConfig and in fact it's possible to break Unity with it.

To reveal the launcher you will need to push the pointer against the left side of the screen.  This is speed and time dependent but you can adjust the sensitivity of the reveal a little bit.